# Is it possible to synchronize multiple VSTS accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a situation where my organization uses a specific project in our VSTS:

{organization-1}.visualstudio.com/{Project.Client}

Some clients have their own as well for the same project:

{organization-2}.visualstudio.com/{Project.Client}

Is it possible to keep these two projects in sync (work-items and code)? Assume that they are both using TFS.

Creating a service EndPoint from {organization-2} to {organization-1} is possible, but doesn't seem to provide much AFAICT since nothing new shows up in the Notifications menu, nor on any of the Work boards relating to the new Endpoint

I've tried creating a Service Hook from {organization-1} to an Azure Service Bus, but there doesn't seem to be any way to consume it from {organization-2} that I can see.

How can I get these two organizations to usefully talk to each other?

Work Item change notifications, Code Check Ins, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the two accounts can’t be synchronized but you can export/import WIT and code from one account to the other.

For export/import WIT, you can use MS excel or other extensions such as [VSTS sync migration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration).